# How to print just the string "value" in bash script using the !! command

Tags: linux, bash

This is a bash scripting exercise that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to print to standard out "value", and only have that as the output. The catch is that you have to use the !! command, which executes the previous command. For example:

```
echo "value"
!!
echo "value"
value
```

is the output when I run those 2 commands. The problem is that it also prints the string literal of the command. How can I get it so just the "value" is printed to stdout?

Comment: You mean only the arguments of the last command executed (or) result of the last command?

Comment: As @Inian is pointing out could your value be a variable? e.g. `echo "$SHELL"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do, you want to execute the command:

```
$ echo "value"
```

Then using *History Expansion* (for the last command `!!`, a *Word Designator* (for the last word `$`) and then a *Modifier* (`p` to print but not execute the command)

```
$ !!$:p
"value"
```

If you need to remove the quotes, you can use the substitution and global modifiers:

```
$ !!$:p:gs/"//
value
```

If that's not what you are looking for, just let me know and I'm happy to work with you further.

Comment: You, of course, can omit the quoting on the first command (it will still work fine) and then you won't need the substitution expression modifier. That being said - I wasn't aware of this feature and it's a very cool one, so I'm happy you did use it and allowed me to learn it :-)